# How to CURL a Facebook ad report

Tags: php, facebook, csv, curl, facebook-ads-api

I want to download a Facebook ad report onto my server using CURL because sadly I dont have access to their Ad API and probably never will do.

I successfully logged in to Facebook using CURL (I got an email from Facebook saying my account had been logged in from somewhere else so bingo)

Code Im using for Facebook log in: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/code/290893/facebook-login-with-curl

But the code that downloads the report isn't working. The CSV just shows blank (As it is default on the server)

Any ideas? You can see the URL to the Facebook CSV file isn't direct so this may be part of the problem.... or maybe something with `$cookie` in the Facebook log in code?

```
$local_file = "letsbonus-ticket.csv";//This is the file where we save the information
$remote_file = "http://www.facebook.com/ads/manage/download_report.php?act=44309118&report_run_id=6016464099986&format=csv&source=email"; //Here is the file we are downloading


$ch = curl_init();
$fp = fopen ($local_file, 'w+');
$ch = curl_init($remote_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: No sorry :( Still really want to know how... because of the exclusivity of the facebook ad api

Comment: If you're not providing the cookie data with your subsequent request(s), then you're attempting to download priveleged data from Facebook without being authenticated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just want to state this is equivalent to scraping in terms of Facebook TOS.

Luckily you don't need to fight the system and play around with cookies.

Facebook Ads API access has been granted to all developers on a tier level.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/access

You should currently have access to development level

> The development access level is designed for development purposes and is ideal for people who are just starting to build out their tool. In this level, you would not yet have customers using your tool. This level is open to all developers, and is intended to build out end-to-end workflows on the API before you get full permissions.
>
> You will be able to use the API on behalf of developers or admins of your app, and you can access up to 5 ad accounts for which those users are admins. To set up the ad account list, refer to the instructions below. Please note that some API calls won't be possible with Development or Basic access because they're potentially associated with multiple accounts, or the affected account can't be identified programmatically.

So using any app you control along with any ad account you own while granting yourself `ads_read` and/or `ads_management` permission (depending on what you need) make an API call to

`/me/adaccounts` and from there you should be able to get ad account info, in your case you can call `/act_44309118` or e.g. `/act_44309118/stats`

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/overview for a full listing of all that is available to you.

Comment: Hi @pdwd,

It seems that just `/act_44309118` will not lead you directly to `report_run_id=6016464099986`.

**Question:** Could you please provide the example of the URL pasted into CURL in order to get `report_run_id=6016464099986` for `act=44309118` as indicated above?

Comment: Post to `/act_ID/insights` take response ID (the report), poll the completion of the job, on completion, query the insights of the completed report `/report_ID/insights`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/best-practices/v2.9

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-report-run/ @AlexSkorokhod

Comment: Thank you for coming back. May be my question was not fully relevant. I have reports pre-created and run_id received by e-mail.

Comment: The node has all properties from [FB docs: /reference/ad-report-run](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-report-run/) e.g.  `async_status = "Job Completed"` etc. But GETting `/report_ID/insights` results into `(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting summary field (results)`. Any ideas how to get the body of the report in this case?

Comment: No idea. Looks like your request is mangled somehow. I don't have any running ad data to test for an email report. Try it by hand (cuRL, dev explorer), supply the correct filters and date presets for your report and check for differences.

I looked at your SO question and you also will need to remove the `&`. When supplying query params it starts with `?` then additional params are appended with `&`. So your query right now is `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/6085730147820/insights&access_token=XXX` as opposed to `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/6085730147820/insights?access_token=XXX`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the `&` and `?` signs misuse. I forgot to update it in the original post. God point. I will contact the Facebook IT support as well. May be they will advise how to proceed further.

Comment: You will need to let them know the object that comes in via email is of a different type than the one created manually.

Email type: `AdReportRun`
Manual type: `AdReportRunV2`

You should be able to file a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: I have found the answer to my problem: The solution is `curl -G -d 'report_run_id=6087450841820'  -d 'format=csv' 'https://www.facebook.com/ads/ads_insights/export_report/'`. Source of info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/best-practices/v2.9#asynchronous

Comment: Thank you Alex, your comment has been very helpful. For some reason the original developers page where the info is available (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/async/v2.8) it's redirecting always to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/best-practices/v2.8, so there's no way no reach the info :(   But tested your solution and works! :)